# Javascript create local object on return statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to make this function not create a global variable while the body is still just an expression on one line (after return).

Seems like if it works with making a global, should be a way to do it with a local

```js
getHashKeyValues = function(h){
    return p={},h.replace(/[\|;]+([^=;]+)=([^;]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){p[k]=v}),p
}

console.log(getHashKeyValues("#/app/path|key1=value1;key2=value2"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare `p` as a function parameter:

```
getHashKeyValues = function(h,p){
    return p={},h.replace(/[\|;]+([^=;]+)=([^;]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){p[k]=v}),p
};
```

That will make `p` a local variable in the function just like if you declared it with `var`. It is perfectly valid to call that function with only one argument, `p` will just be `undefined` until it gets assigned a value.

Answer (score 4):

Declare `p` as a `var` in the function.

```
getHashKeyValues = function(h) {
    var p = {};
    h.replace(/[\|;]+([^=;]+)=([^;]*)/gi,function(s,k,v){p[k]=v});
    return p;
}
```

And make it readable–this is an awful way to write this.

*Edit* Oh, I missed the "one line" requirement, which disqualifies my answer.

Even though I'm right :p

Comment: @baao It's actually kind of impressive :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Dave Newton, but if you really want to do this, add `p` as an second parameter, then modify it.

```
getHashKeyValues = function(h, p){
    return p={},h.replace(/[\|;]+([^=;]+)=([^;]*)/gi,function(s,k,v)    {p[k]=v}),p
}

console.log(getHashKeyValues("#/app/path|key1=value1;key2=value2"))
```